# What are the ways to stream live video to a webpage on iOS, except WebRTC?

Tags: ios, video-streaming, media-source

WebRTC requires too much processing power on server so doing it massively will be cost-prohibitive.

For nearly all other platforms - both for Windows and Mac - Chrome, Safari desktop, even IE and Edge, and Android - there is a Media Source Extensions API (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Source_Extensions) which allows sending stream over websockets and play it, it works. Problem is just with iOS.

Is there anything better (lower latency) than HLS which would work for me?

If not, is there a WebRTC server which is free and better scalable/more stable than Kurento Media Server (https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-media-server)?

There is a jsmpeg player http://jsmpeg.com/ but it is MPEG-1 only so will require unacceptable amount of bandwidth. There is broadway.js but it does not support audio...

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anything better (lower latency) than HLS which would work for me?

HTTP Progressive is a fine technology for this.  It can be ran at much lower latencies than a segmented technology like DASH or HLS, and requires very little in terms of server-side resources.  Look into Icecast for your server, and FFmpeg as your source.

There's no point in sending video over Web Sockets, unless you're implementing a bi-directional protocol.  This isn't uncommon for ABR support, but it's definitely not the most efficient or simple way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

Since you don't want to implement webRTC by yourself and need lower latency than HLS, I would prefer a media server. There are many media servers available in the market. But if you are looking for free and open source media server, your options are limited to few.

I would suggest red5 media server which is free and open source. Please check [this](http://red5.org/) link to find more about red5. If you use free red 5 media server you need little knowledge of java. Red5 also has a paid version called [red5 pro](https://red5pro.com/) which has better webRTC support and higher capabilities. Red5 is mostly for rtmp with flash player pulgin and its fairly new for [red 5 webRTC](https://github.com/rajdeeprath/red5-webrtc-demo) streaming.

Also you can use [wowza streaming engine](https://www.wowza.com/products/streaming-engine) trail version with limited number of connections. So these are the easiest options for you.